# List of documents if boyfriend is my sponsor? Schengen Greece Visa

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, greece

A little background of our relationship:

My boyfriend and I live in Dubai. We met in the year of 2017 in Dubai and have been dating for two and a half years.

Now, we are planning to travel to Greece and Spain in the span of 10 days in August. However, the balance of my account is currently insufficient(I'm a working student so im paying for my tuition fees). Because of this, my boyfriend will sponsor me during our trip. If he is to sponsor me, what documents should we provide to the embassy besides 6 months of bank statements, Passport and uae visa copies?

P.S. I am going to apply to Greece. Does anyone had the same situation as mine? If so, i’d like to know what you’ve provided so i can somehow have ideas. Thank you very much

Comment: Do the visa application instructions not clearly answer your question?

Comment: Probably his employment contract as proof of his source of funds, and proof of your student status.

Comment: @david richerby sadly yes. They didn’t specify any details about sponsorship visa. If they provided these details I wouldn’t be here in the first place

Comment: Your relationship with your sponsor has no impact on the requirements, the sponsor has must have finances and reasons to give you the money. A romantic relationship sounds like a good reason, but note that it is also a reason to stay with you if you decide to stay in violation of the visa (that's the kind of things the authorities also has to think abut).